# Visual estudio incompatible ".rptproj"

Tags: visual-studio

Estoy dandole mantenimiento a un proyecto algo viejo, apenas lo abro en visual studio me tira el un error que dice:

Esta version de Visual Studio no puede abrir los siguiente proyectos. Puede que los tipos de proyectos no esten instalados o que no sean compatibles con esta version de Visual Studio.

Para obtener mas informacion sobre como habilitar estos tipos de proyectos o como migrar sus activos, consulte la informacion del "Informe de migracion" que se muestra al hacer click en aceptar.

NOMBREDELPROYECTO.rptproj

Comment: te aconsejo borrar la carpteta bin y recompilar

Answer (score 1):

La extensión "rptproj" pertenece a informes diseñados con SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS).

Para poder abrirlos requiere de la instalación de Reporting Services o bien de una extensión en Visual Studio (‘Extensions & Updates‘ y buscas 'Microsoft Reporting Services Projects'). Tambien en la tienes en el [marketplace de Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio).